# How to check if every X number is met within a variable?

Tags: python, numbers, conditional-statements

In Python, I am accumulating a variable in loops until a certain condition is met. However, how can I check for example every 100 accumulated number is met in "var1". I could do it manually (going "if var1 == 100, 200, 300 etc) but that's not good.

```
var1 = 0

while var1 != 10000:
    var1 += 1
```

Comment: I've never seen that before, please elaborate?

Comment: How about `for var1 in range(0, 10000, 100)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use Modulus operator `%`:

```
var1 = 0
while var1 != 10000:
    if var1%10 == 0:
        do something
    var1 += 1
```

> > Modulus operator, it is used for remainder division on integers, typically, but in Python can be used for floating point numbers. The % (modulo) operator yields the remainder from the division of the first argument by the second

Comment: Hold on, but this is when you already know the outcome so you just put a percentage of that outcome. What about when you don't know that var1 will be 10000, so just check every 100 that is accumulated?

Comment: the `%` here has nothing to do with percentage (other than sharing the symbol)